# What does "step" mean in stepSimulation and what do its parameters mean in Bullet Physics?

Tags: bulletphysics

What does the term "STEP" means in bullet physics?

What does the function `stepSimulation()` and its parameters mean?

I have read the [documentation](http://bulletphysics.org/mediawiki-1.5.8/index.php/Stepping_The_World) but i could not get hold of anything.

Any valid explanation would be of great help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
btDynamicsWorld::stepSimulation(
   btScalar timeStep,
   int maxSubSteps=1,
   btScalar fixedTimeStep=btScalar(1.)/btScalar(60.));
```

`timeStep` - time passed after last simulation.

Internally simulation is done for some internal constant steps. `fixedTimeStep`

`fixedTimeStep` ~~~ 0.01666666 = 1/60

if `timeStep` is 0.1 then it will include 6 (`timeStep / fixedTimeStep`) internal simulations.

To make glider movements BulletPhysics interpolate final step results according reminder after  division (`timeStep / fixedTimeStep`)

Answer (score 12):

I know I'm late, but I thought the accepted answer was only marginally better than the documentation's description.

`timeStep`: The amount of seconds, not milliseconds, passed since the last call to `stepSimulation`.

`maxSubSteps`: Should generally stay at one so Bullet interpolates current values on its own.  A value of zero implies a variable tick rate, meaning Bullet advances the simulation exactly `timeStep` seconds instead of interpolating.  This feature is buggy and not recommended.  A value greater than one must *always* satisfy the equation `timeStep < maxSubSteps * fixedTimeStep` or you're losing time in the simulation.

`fixedTimeStep`: Inversely proportional to the simulation's resolution.  Resolution increases as this value decreases.  Keep in mind that a higher resolution means it takes more CPU.

Comment: Is `timeStep <= maxSubSteps * fixedTimeStep` possible? What is the correct configuration if I want to advance the physics simulation by exactly 10 (sub)steps, each 0.01 sec long such that the simulation has advanced a total of 0.1 secs at the end of the call to `stepSimulation(...)`?

Answer (score 2):

- `timeStep` - the amount of time in seconds to step the simulation by. Typically you're going to be passing it the time since you last called it.
- `maxSubSteps` - the maximum number of steps that Bullet is allowed to take each time you call it.
- `fixedTimeStep` - regulates *resolution* of the simulation. If your balls penetrates your walls instead of colliding with them try to decrease it.

---

Here i would like to address the issue in Proxy's answer about special meaning of value `1` for `maxSubSteps`. There is only one special value, that is `0` and you most likely don't want to use it because then simulation will go with non-constant time step. All other values are the same. Let's have a look at [the actual code](https://github.com/bulletphysics/bullet3/blob/master/src/BulletDynamics/Dynamics/btDiscreteDynamicsWorld.cpp):

```cpp
if (maxSubSteps)
{
    m_localTime += timeStep;
    ...
    if (m_localTime >= fixedTimeStep)
    {
        numSimulationSubSteps = int(m_localTime / fixedTimeStep);
        m_localTime -= numSimulationSubSteps * fixedTimeStep;
    }
}
...
if (numSimulationSubSteps)
{
    //clamp the number of substeps, to prevent simulation grinding spiralling down to a halt
    int clampedSimulationSteps = (numSimulationSubSteps > maxSubSteps) ? maxSubSteps : numSimulationSubSteps;
    ...
    for (int i = 0; i < clampedSimulationSteps; i++)
    {
        internalSingleStepSimulation(fixedTimeStep);
        synchronizeMotionStates();
    }
}
```

So, there is nothing special about `maxSubSteps` equal to `1`. You should really abide this formula `timeStep < maxSubSteps * fixedTimeStep` if you don't want to *lose* time.